# Flutter Hive how to clear cache

Tags: flutter, caching, flutter-hive

I use hive: ^1.4.4+1 and hive_flutter: ^0.3.1. I have a problem with box.get after updating a box. It gets the cached version of the object, not the version in the .hive file. For example:

```
Box box = await Hive.openBox('box1');
box.put('configData', configData);
ConfigData configDataToRestore = await box.get('configData'); //Works as expected
(configData is now updated)
box.put('configData', configData); //The .hive file is updated as it should
ConfigData configDataToRestore = await box.get('configData'); //Returns the first version from the cache, not the updated version
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to clear the cache?

Comment: If I restart the app and then do the box.get, I get the updated version.

Comment: Adding another await Hive.initFlutter() just before the second box.get seems to solve the problem. But it feels like a hack.